# can we interprete a vectors space over a field as a quotient space of the vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

can we interprete a vectors space $V$ over a field $F$ as a quotient space of the vector sapce with $F$ as kernel ?

$V$ over $F$ is a set of vectors, where $(V, +)$ is an abiliean group with identity $0_v$, and $\exists $ a scalar product operation $(F,V)\mapsto V$.

I am wondering if we can interpret it $V$ as $V/F$ or not ?

Probably I am wrong, could someone illstruate with an example to refresh my mind ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you write $V/F$, you must have some equivalence relation in mind, like "$v_1 \sim k v_1$ for any $k \in F$"; can you explain what is the equivalence relation you're thinking of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field $F$ is not a subspace of $V$, so write something as $V/K$ has no meaning.

In other words: to define a quotient space we need an equivalence relation $\sim$ such that for two vectors $\vec v$, $\vec u$ of $V$ we have $ \vec u \sim \vec v \iff \vec u- \vec v \in X$, where $X$ is a subspace of $V$. Since $K$ is not a subspace of $V$ we cannot define $V/K$.

Interpreting your question in a bit different manner, we can ask if ve can write $V=V/N$ for some subspace $N$ isomorphic to $K$, thinking to $K$ as a $1$-dimensional vector space over itself. But in this case the answer is no. You can think to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and use as $N$ any $1$-dimensional subspace (a straight line between the origin): $\mathbb{R}^n/N$ is the space of all lines parallels to $N$.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n/N$ also is the space of all lines in $\mathbb R^n$ parallel to $N$, nothing special about $n=2$ there.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo! I edit.